# JS Regex: (a|b) Matches the a or the b part of the subexpression. Different behaviour when a and b switched

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace *2%* with ''(empty) using regexp concept. If input string is either *%* or *2%*, it should be replaced with ''(empty):

```js
const str = "2%";

console.log(`2%`.replace(/^\d%$|\d(?=%)/, ''));
console.log(`2%`.replace(/\d(?=%)|^\d%$/, ''));
```

`(a|b) Matches the a or the b part of the subexpression.`

`"2%".replace(/^\d%$|\d(?=%)/, '')`. This works well.

But, `"2%".replace(/\d(?=%)|^\d%$/, '')` does not.

Comment: So what is your question and problem? You appear to have working source code....

Comment: The left side of the `|` matches, so that's what's replaced. What exactly is it that's surprising here?

Comment: @Pointy, Does it work like short-circuit operator?

Comment: Yes, the first alternative that matches "wins".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in what the regex tries to match first. The left expression takes precedence. The right is only tried when the left one fails to match.